# Contact Form - Email not sent when form submitted

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to implement a contact form for my website, but when I submit the form, there is no email that comes to my email address. Validation works fine.
Here is the PHP file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])){

    $email_to = "you@yourdomain.com";
    $email_subject = "AHU Enquiry";

    function died($error){
        echo "We are very sorry, but there are error(s) found with the form you submitted.";
        echo "These error(s) appear below.<br/><br/>";
        echo $error."<br/><br/>";
        echo "Please go back and fix these error(s).<br/><br/>";
        die();  
    }

    if(!isset($_POST['first_name'])||
    !isset($_POST['last_name'])||
    !isset($_POST['email'])||
    !isset($_POST['telephone'])||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])){
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');   
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email_from = $_POST['email'];
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

    if(!preg_match($email_exp, $email_from)){
        $error_message .= 'The Email address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br/>';        
    }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

    if(!preg_match($string_exp, $first_name)){
        $error_message .= 'The Firt Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br/>';
    }

    if(!preg_match($string_exp, $last_name)){
        $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br/>';
    }

    if(strlen($comments)<2){
        $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered does not appear to be valid.<br/>';
    }

    if(strlen($error_message)>0){
        died($error_message);
    }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string){
        $bad = array("content-type", "bcc:", "to:", "cc:", "href");
        return str_replace($bad, "", $string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

    $headers = 'From: $first_name $last_name<$email_from>\r\n';

    mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

?>

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php       

    }
?>
```

Could somebody please point me in the right direction?

Here is the screenshot of the error.
[image]

Comment: I know this isn't an answer you would expect, but I'd recommend you to use some of the mail apis, they're really simple to use and also very reliable, since that's their business. I like to use [mandrill](https://mandrill.com/), they allow you to send 12k mails for free per month, which is more than enough for testing and personal projects, or even small production projects.

Comment: That is an interesting thought, I will look into that

Comment: They're offering great php API, you can [start here](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/index.php.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not set up a Mail Server. Every time you want the email to be sent after the contact form is submitted, you should have an outgoing (SMTP) mail server settings so that your email is actually sent to the desired email address. The easiest way to do this is by using [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) PHP code. It is much simpler than using the traditional mail() function. Here is the sample code:

```
require_once 'SwiftMailer/lib/swift_required.php';

if(isset($_POST['email'])){
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email_from = $_POST['email'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

$email_message = "Form details below.<br/><br/>";
$email_message .= "First Name: ".$first_name."<br/>";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".$last_name."<br/>";
$email_message .= "Email: ".$email_from."<br/>";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".$telephone."<br/>";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".$comments."<br/>";

ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl')
        ->setUsername('youremail@gmail.com')
        ->setPassword('yourpassword');

    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('AHU Enquiry')
        ->setFrom(array('youremail@gmail.com'=>'Sales Enquiries'))
        ->setTo(array('youremail@gmail.com'=>'Lead Recipients'))
        ->setSubject('Enquiry')
        ->setBody($email_message, 'text/html');
$result = $mailer->send($message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that there is either an error in the information that you are providing through $post or you do not have a mail server setup

Try commenting out that entire block of code and attempt to use example 2 on the php mail api site

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

If this works then there is a problem with your code, if it doesn't work it's a problem with your mail server

The error log should provide info as well.

Comment: Are we required to configure outgoing and incoming mail settings? If so, how do we do that......

Comment: Currently the email should come to my Gmail account.

Comment: Yes you must set up a mail server else you won't be able to send mail.  If you are using Ubuntu then sudo apt-get install postfix will install a mail server for you.